# Haskell - Instance of Fractional Int required for definition of filename?

Tags: haskell

I'm an amateur at Haskell, trying to run through an infinite list of approximations to the square root of "x", where "acc" represents the generation this step is on. However, when I run the code below, I get the underlying error.

```
as' x acc = ( last(take (acc-1) (as' x (acc-1)))
+ (acc / last(take (acc-1) (as' x (acc-1)))) ) / 2 : as' x (acc+1)
```

`ERROR "a5.hs":34 - Instance of Fractional Int required for definition of as'`

Also, when I try applying this type code, I get an error:

```
as' :: Float -> Float -> Float
```

`Type error in application

*** Expression     : (last (take (acc - 1) (as' x (acc - 1))) + acc / last (take (acc - 1) (as' x (acc - 1)))) / 2 : as' x (acc + 1)

*** Term           : as' x (acc + 1)

*** Type           : Float

*** Does not match : [a]`

EDIT: To offer you some clarity, I want to use this function in the context of a list.
e.g. as x = [1, as' x 2].
The idea is that this will accumulate an infinite list, since as' will recursively call itself. Hence why I felt I could operate on a list here.

Can anyone please offer me some clarity?

Comment: you can define a helper `as'' start current =
    let next = (current + (start / current)) / 2
    in current : (as'' start next)` and then `as' x = as'' x x`, although using iterate is a better idea

Comment: Don't use Hugs, it's old and not maintained.

Answer (score 12):

The type signature of `take` is

```
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
```

Here's how you are using `take`:

```
take (acc-1) (as' x (acc-1))
```

So we can conclude that

```
(acc-1)         :: Int    -- first parameter to `take`
acc             :: Int    -- therefore

(as' x (acc-1)) :: [a]    -- second parameter to `take`, we don't know what `a` is
```

But your code says

```
as' :: Float -> Float -> Float
as' x acc = ...
```

From which we deduce

```
x               :: Float  -- first parameter to `as'`
acc             :: Float  -- second parameter to `as'`
(as' x (acc-1)) :: Float  -- result of `as'`
```

Which leads to a couple of contradictions:

- `acc` cannot be an `Int` and a `Float` at the same time
- `(as' x (acc-1))` cannot be an `[a]` and a `Float` at the same time --- this is what the second error message is trying to tell you

Ultimately, you are trying to use `take` on something that is not a list. I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

---

You probably intended to have the signature

```
as' :: Float -> Int -> [Float]
```

That should (I've not tested it) fix the type errors above, but still leaves a more fundamental problem: whenever you compute the *n*th element of the list, you compute the *n-1*th element of the list anew *twice* (and so on, back to the start of the list: exponential growth of recalculation), even though presumably this element has already been computed. There is no *sharing* going on.

e.g. consider

```
as' x acc = ( prev + (acc / prev) ) / 2 : as' x (acc+1)
  where prev = last(take (acc-1) (as' x (acc-1)))
```

This is still inefficient: you still recompute previous elements of the list. But now you only recompute all previous elements once when computing the next element.

(It would also be remiss of me not to point out that `last(take (acc-1) (as' x (acc-1)))` can be simplified to `(as' x (acc-1)) !! (acc-2)`.)

---

The usual way to generate an infinite list where each element depends only on the previous element is to use [`iterate`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:iterate).

The complication is that you have each element depending on an accumulator as well as depending on the previous element.  We will get round that by incorporating the accumulator into each element of the list.  When we are done we will throw away the accumulators to produce our final infinite list.

```
approxRoots :: Float -> [Float]
approxRoots x = map fst $ iterate next (x, 1)
      -- I don't know what your initial approximation should be
      -- I've put `x` but that's probably wrong
  where next (prev, acc) = (prev + acc / prev, acc + 1)
        -- First element of each pair is the approximation,
        -- second element of each pair is the "accumulator" (actually an index)
        -- I've probably transcribed your formula wrongly
```

Comment: It's nice how you derived the problem from the signature, but it would've been even nicer if you had derived it from the error message. :-}

Comment: @FrerichRaabe OK, you post an answer that derives the problem from the error message, and I'll upvote it :-)

Comment: Terribly sorry for the confusion. I'll edit my post now for clarity.

Comment: @dave4420: Your wish is my command. :-) Btw, I didn't meant to sound too negative (I actually upvoted you!)!

Comment: @FrerichRaabe No worries. I didn't mean to sound snarky, if I did, but I only have so much procrastination today.

Comment: Hummm, reasonable people on the Internet.  Up-votes all around I guess.

Answer (score 7):

[dave4420's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13989138/91757) is already very nice, I just want to share how you can get the most from the error message which the compiler gave you. Here is it again:

```
*** Expression : (last (take (acc - 1) (as' x (acc - 1))) + acc / last (take (acc - 1) (as' x (acc - 1)))) / 2 : as' x (acc + 1)
*** Term : as' x (acc + 1)
*** Type : Float
*** Does not match : [a]
```

This means that the `as' x (acc + 1)` part in the long expression was expected to yield a list, but it actually gives a `Float` value.

- Why does the compiler expect it to be a list? Well, let's see where the term is used in the expression:

  ```
  (last .... ) / 2 : as' x (acc + 1)
  ```

  I.e., it's used as the second argument to the `(:)` function, and the compiler knows that the second argument to this function has to be a list (the compiler knows that the signature of  `(:)` is `a -> [a] -> [a]` though it doesn't mention that part in the error message).
- Why is it actually a `Float`? Since you didn't provide a function signature, the compiler deduced it for you and actually printed it as well:

  ```
  as' :: Float -> Float -> Float
  ```

  So the compiler determined that `as'` takes two `Float` values and yields a `Float` value. I don't know from the top of my head why it did that.

My advice is to start debugging this issue by explicitely writing down a function signature yourself. Doing so will cause a different error message which is closer to the cause of the mismatch between your expectation and the actual code.

Comment: it was OP who manually provided the `as'` type, so it was a conflict between user provided type declaration and the inferred one.

Comment: The error message looks like it came from Hugs, not GHC. "Why is it actually a `Float`?" Because of `/` (and defaulting? or the type of `x` as deduced from the rest of the program?).

Comment: @soulcheck: Ah, the signature was really provided by the OP? To me it looked as if it was part of the `***` block which he quoted, but I now see that there's a thin white line between the two...

Comment: @soulcheck: I always only worked with GHC, and I never quite grok'ed how it decides which number type to use (maybe it's indeed `/`). Unfortunately I never bothered to learn how it works either, I just always `fromIntegral`'ed it into submission. :-]